# How do I ensure my Android build is not darker than in Editor?

Tags: unity, lighting, per-pixel

My scene on the Android Build looks much darker. Based on my research about the  topic, and from the texture of the light on the spheres, I assume it is because the light uses **per vertex** render mode on Andriod.

I am trying to force **per pixel** render on Android, these are the things I have tried:

- set the **Rendering** to **Important** of the **Light** on the scene (There is only 1 directional)
- check the values of my **RenderPipeline** asset (the one came with the LWRP Template project), the **Main light** is **Per Pixel**, **Additional Light** (which doesn't seem to matter) is also **Per Pixel**
- set the **Preset Light's Render** type to **Important** in the **Preset Manager**

I will have infinite levels, the map changes dynamically, so Baking the light is not an option.

Can I achieve this somehow? Or at least force my editor to use per pixel so I can light up my scene more intuitively.

[image]

Comment: Note that the skybox also looks considerably darker and more saturated on your device. This cannot be due to per-pixel versus per-vertex lighting. So I think the root cause of your issue is something else. It looks suspiciously similar to the difference between linear RGB and gamma-compressed, so the first thing I'd investigate would be your gamma settings, rendering colour space, and HDR settings.

Comment: Well they are in the same colorspace, so that's not an issue. Could you please give me some properties worth checking maybe? I've played around the HDR settings I could find.

Comment: [You symptoms sound similar to the problem reported here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/lwrp-android-linear-color-space-looks-very-different-on-different-devices.652750/). If you're using an Android device that uses OpenGL ES2 it may not support linear colour blending space. Have you tried using gamma blending space instead? Editing your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the Unity setup needed to demonstrate the problem and the specific devices the problem does/does not occur on can also help us narrow down the potential causes.